# What's the document loader used on Youtube?

Tags: reactjs, material-design

I want to use a loader such as the one on Youtube before the content is loaded. On youtube, every piece of content uses a light gray color loader before rendering the actual content. It is made of squares and circles to simulate the actual content about to be rendered.

Do you know what it is ? Surprisingly, I couldn't find it neither on material-ui nor via a google search.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the solution to my problem.

What I was looking for is called "placeholder UI", or "skeleton screen".

In my case, I want to use it with ReactJS. Semantic UI React has the placeholder part of the library :

> https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/placeholder/#content-line

Material-UI, and other styling libraries do not. There are however external packages for that, such as :

> https://github.com/buildo/react-placeholder
>
> https://github.com/danilowoz/react-content-loader
>
> https://github.com/dvtng/react-loading-skeleton

It's also possible to implement skeleton screens oneself using a combination of html, svg and css.